# GetX wrong initialization place of widget data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using GetX. I need to generate data for list visibility.

```
class TableController extends GetxController {

  List<bool> columnVisibility = []; 
  
  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    columnVisibility = List.generate(getColumns.length, (index) => true);
  }
      List<GridColumn> get getColumns {
        return <GridColumn>[
                          GridColumn(
                            columnName: 'name',
                            visible: columnVisibility[0],
                            label: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Text('name'),
                            ),
                          )
                        ];

      }

}
```

Error:

```
Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0
```

Line:

```
visible: columnVisibility[0]
```

So I am doing init in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

In `onInit` method , you are initialising `columnVisibility` list by `List.generate` which is using `getColumns` which is already using `columnVisibility` list so it is obvious it will throw error as it don't have any data and you are trying to access value from list using `0` index

So you may change this line

```
visible: columnVisibility[0],
```

To

```
visible: columnVisibility.length > 1 ? columnVisibility[0] : false, 

//assuming default value false to return if we don't have
```

Exactly i am not getting what you are trying to achieve but issue is just because of it